# Table of imports and exports by value from country to country

Tags: economics, economy

I am looking for a list that lists for each world country, the total amount of imports and exports to and from that country, in some currency, as well as a table that has in its x,y position the entry listing the total amount of imports and exports from country x to country y.

Where can I find this data?

Thanks.

Comment: Wikipedia is almost always a good start: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_countries_by_exports https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_countries_by_imports

Answer (score 2):

Check out https://comtrade.un.org/

Particularly https://unstats.un.org/unsd/trade/data/tables.asp#annual (Table 41: Exports by provenance and destination)